# how to use first in IIF conditon Rdlc

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, rdlc

i am using four dataset for binding a rdlc, and for one text value i am using one dataset and use  below condition but this is working.

```
IIF(Fields!Str_BVN.Value is Nothing,"Not Verified","Verified")
```

But when i use two dataset and use below IIF condition this give me exception

```
First(IIF(Fields!Str_BVN.Value is Nothing,"Not Verified","Verified"),"DataSetGetPeople")
```

can you please tell me what i am doing mistake or what i need to do. Many solution that i found they are telling that try to use one dataset. But i really need to use four dataset for my report

**Excretion**

```
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: The specified operation is not valid
```

Thanks for your reply and comments

Comment: Your function can't work, if you simplify it by taking await the if and just using one of the possibility you would get this First("Not Verified","DataSetGetPeople"). I'm not sure if I understand your problem, but you maybe wanted to do this? IIF(First(Fields!Str_BVN.Value is Nothing,"DataSetGetPeople"),"Not Verified","Verified").

Comment: What Rapheal suggested is correct and might already fix your problem. However there are some other possible mistakes you're making that could be the cause of your problem. You'll have to give some more information though. Is this a single textbox you wish to display this value? Or is this a value inside the cell of a table/rectangle? Is this textbox placed inside the body of your report and not the header/footer ? Have you heard of parameters and isn't it possible you could use a report parameter for this instead of a new dataset?